# How can I vertically center images inside flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have tried using flexbox to vertically center the images which was working but I noticed that if you did a hard refresh on firefox the slider would disappear this was due to flexbox for some reason. I have created a demo in codepen but for some reason flexbox doesn't work now. I need an alternate solution to flexbox anyway. Can you help?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 4000,           
        animationSpeed: 600, 
        pausePlay: true,
        controlNav: true,
        directionNav: false,
        pauseText: '',             
        playText: '',
        pauseOnHover: true,
    });
  });
```

```css
.slider{
    display: -webkit-box!important; 
    display: -moz-box!important;
    display: -ms-flexbox!important;
    display: -webkit-flex!important; 
    display: flex!important;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-height: 600px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.slides li{
    position: relative;
}

.slides li{
    max-height: 600px;
}

.flex-control-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex-control-paging li a{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #f04d43;
}

.flex-active{
    background-color: #404041;
}

.flex-pauseplay{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
      <li>
          <img src="http://79.170.40.172/allianceworkforce.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/slider_image.png" alt="" />
      </li>
    
    <li>
          <img src="http://79.170.40.172/allianceworkforce.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/slider_image.png" alt="" />
      </li>
    
    <li>
          <img src="http://79.170.40.172/allianceworkforce.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/slider_image.png" alt="" />
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I can't upload the full code sorry. Please go to my code pen if you wish to help. thanks  https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/JyOjOX

Comment: you only set a max-height, there is no option to vertical-align your image when the slider exceeds the ilage height. Can you clarify ? is it about cropping image ? ... alternative can be inline-block and white-space for a method previous the flex model

Comment: @G-Cyr basically I want the image to overflow evenly at the top and bottom. At the moment it only overflows out the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone wanting to center images vertically in flexslider this I how I achieved  it.

```
.slider{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-height: 600px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 384px;
}

.slides, .slides > li{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box!important;
    display: -moz-box!important;
    display: -ms-flexbox!important;
    display: -webkit-flex!important;
    display: flex!important;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.slider img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.slides li{
    position: relative;
}

.slides li{
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following working-for-me code at https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider/issues/2217999

```
.flexslider .slides {
    zoom: 1;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)  & [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) could be used to crop image from center when needed:

```
.slides li img {
  width:100%;
  object-fit:none;
  object-position: center center;
}
```

example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvOwgo

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 4000,           
        animationSpeed: 600, 
        pausePlay: true,
        controlNav: true,
        directionNav: false,
        pauseText: '',             
        playText: '',
        pauseOnHover: true,
    });
  });
!function($){var e=!0;$.flexslider=function(t,a){var n=$(t);n.vars=$.extend({},$.flexslider.defaults,a);var i=n.vars.namespace,s=window.navigator&&window.navigator.msPointerEnabled&&window.MSGesture,r=("ontouchstart"in window||s||window.DocumentTouch&&document instanceof DocumentTouch)&&n.vars.touch,o="click touchend MSPointerUp keyup",l="",c,d="vertical"===n.vars.direction,u=n.vars.reverse,v=n.vars.itemWidth>0,p="fade"===n.vars.animation,m=""!==n.vars.asNavFor,f={};$.data(t,"flexslider",n),f={init:function(){n.animating=!1,n.currentSlide=parseInt(n.vars.startAt?n.vars.startAt:0,10),isNaN(n.currentSlide)&&(n.currentSlide=0),n.animatingTo=n.currentSlide,n.atEnd=0===n.currentSlide||n.currentSlide===n.last,n.containerSelector=n.vars.selector.substr(0,n.vars.selector.search(" ")),n.slides=$(n.vars.selector,n),n.container=$(n.containerSelector,n),n.count=n.slides.length,n.syncExists=$(n.vars.sync).length>0,"slide"===n.vars.animation&&(n.vars.animation="swing"),n.prop=d?"top":"marginLeft",n.args={},n.manualPause=!1,n.stopped=!1,n.started=!1,n.startTimeout=null,n.transitions=!n.vars.video&&!p&&n.vars.useCSS&&function(){var e=document.createElement("div"),t=["perspectiveProperty","WebkitPerspective","MozPerspective","OPerspective","msPerspective"];for(var a in t)if(void 0!==e.style[t[a]])return n.pfx=t[a].replace("Perspective","").toLowerCase(),n.prop="-"+n.pfx+"-transform",!0;return!1}(),n.ensureAnimationEnd="",""!==n.vars.controlsContainer&&(n.controlsContainer=$(n.vars.controlsContainer).length>0&&$(n.vars.controlsContainer)),""!==n.vars.manualControls&&(n.manualControls=$(n.vars.manualControls).length>0&&$(n.vars.manualControls)),""!==n.vars.customDirectionNav&&(n.customDirectionNav=2===$(n.vars.customDirectionNav).length&&$(n.vars.customDirectionNav)),n.vars.randomize&&(n.slides.sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-.5}),n.container.empty().append(n.slides)),n.doMath(),n.setup("init"),n.vars.controlNav&&f.controlNav.setup(),n.vars.directionNav&&f.directionNav.setup(),n.vars.keyboard&&(1===$(n.containerSelector).length||n.vars.multipleKeyboard)&&$(document).bind("keyup",function(e){var t=e.keyCode;if(!n.animating&&(39===t||37===t)){var a=39===t?n.getTarget("next"):37===t?n.getTarget("prev"):!1;n.flexAnimate(a,n.vars.pauseOnAction)}}),n.vars.mousewheel&&n.bind("mousewheel",function(e,t,a,i){e.preventDefault();var s=0>t?n.getTarget("next"):n.getTarget("prev");n.flexAnimate(s,n.vars.pauseOnAction)}),n.vars.pausePlay&&f.pausePlay.setup(),n.vars.slideshow&&n.vars.pauseInvisible&&f.pauseInvisible.init(),n.vars.slideshow&&(n.vars.pauseOnHover&&n.hover(function(){n.manualPlay||n.manualPause||n.pause()},function(){n.manualPause||n.manualPlay||n.stopped||n.play()}),n.vars.pauseInvisible&&f.pauseInvisible.isHidden()||(n.vars.initDelay>0?n.startTimeout=setTimeout(n.play,n.vars.initDelay):n.play())),m&&f.asNav.setup(),r&&n.vars.touch&&f.touch(),(!p||p&&n.vars.smoothHeight)&&$(window).bind("resize orientationchange focus",f.resize),n.find("img").attr("draggable","false"),setTimeout(function(){n.vars.start(n)},200)},asNav:{setup:function(){n.asNav=!0,n.animatingTo=Math.floor(n.currentSlide/n.move),n.currentItem=n.currentSlide,n.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(n.currentItem).addClass(i+"active-slide"),s?(t._slider=n,n.slides.each(function(){var e=this;e._gesture=new MSGesture,e._gesture.target=e,e.addEventListener("MSPointerDown",function(e){e.preventDefault(),e.currentTarget._gesture&&e.currentTarget._gesture.addPointer(e.pointerId)},!1),e.addEventListener("MSGestureTap",function(e){e.preventDefault();var t=$(this),a=t.index();$(n.vars.asNavFor).data("flexslider").animating||t.hasClass("active")||(n.direction=n.currentItem<a?"next":"prev",n.flexAnimate(a,n.vars.pauseOnAction,!1,!0,!0))})})):n.slides.on(o,function(e){e.preventDefault();var t=$(this),a=t.index(),s=t.offset().left-$(n).scrollLeft();0>=s&&t.hasClass(i+"active-slide")?n.flexAnimate(n.getTarget("prev"),!0):$(n.vars.asNavFor).data("flexslider").animating||t.hasClass(i+"active-slide")||(n.direction=n.currentItem<a?"next":"prev",n.flexAnimate(a,n.vars.pauseOnAction,!1,!0,!0))})}},controlNav:{setup:function(){n.manualControls?f.controlNav.setupManual():f.controlNav.setupPaging()},setupPaging:function(){var e="thumbnails"===n.vars.controlNav?"control-thumbs":"control-paging",t=1,a,s;if(n.controlNavScaffold=$('<ol class="'+i+"control-nav "+i+e+'"></ol>'),n.pagingCount>1)for(var r=0;r<n.pagingCount;r++){s=n.slides.eq(r),void 0===s.attr("data-thumb-alt")&&s.attr("data-thumb-alt","");var c=""!==s.attr("data-thumb-alt")?c=' alt="'+s.attr("data-thumb-alt")+'"':"";if(a="thumbnails"===n.vars.controlNav?'<img src="'+s.attr("data-thumb")+'"'+c+"/>":'<a href="#">'+t+"</a>","thumbnails"===n.vars.controlNav&&!0===n.vars.thumbCaptions){var d=s.attr("data-thumbcaption");""!==d&&void 0!==d&&(a+='<span class="'+i+'caption">'+d+"</span>")}n.controlNavScaffold.append("<li>"+a+"</li>"),t++}n.controlsContainer?$(n.controlsContainer).append(n.controlNavScaffold):n.append(n.controlNavScaffold),f.controlNav.set(),f.controlNav.active(),n.controlNavScaffold.delegate("a, img",o,function(e){if(e.preventDefault(),""===l||l===e.type){var t=$(this),a=n.controlNav.index(t);t.hasClass(i+"active")||(n.direction=a>n.currentSlide?"next":"prev",n.flexAnimate(a,n.vars.pauseOnAction))}""===l&&(l=e.type),f.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},setupManual:function(){n.controlNav=n.manualControls,f.controlNav.active(),n.controlNav.bind(o,function(e){if(e.preventDefault(),""===l||l===e.type){var t=$(this),a=n.controlNav.index(t);t.hasClass(i+"active")||(a>n.currentSlide?n.direction="next":n.direction="prev",n.flexAnimate(a,n.vars.pauseOnAction))}""===l&&(l=e.type),f.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},set:function(){var e="thumbnails"===n.vars.controlNav?"img":"a";n.controlNav=$("."+i+"control-nav li "+e,n.controlsContainer?n.controlsContainer:n)},active:function(){n.controlNav.removeClass(i+"active").eq(n.animatingTo).addClass(i+"active")},update:function(e,t){n.pagingCount>1&&"add"===e?n.controlNavScaffold.append($('<li><a href="#">'+n.count+"</a></li>")):1===n.pagingCount?n.controlNavScaffold.find("li").remove():n.controlNav.eq(t).closest("li").remove(),f.controlNav.set(),n.pagingCount>1&&n.pagingCount!==n.controlNav.length?n.update(t,e):f.controlNav.active()}},directionNav:{setup:function(){var e=$('<ul class="'+i+'direction-nav"><li class="'+i+'nav-prev"><a class="'+i+'prev" href="#">'+n.vars.prevText+'</a></li><li class="'+i+'nav-next"><a class="'+i+'next" href="#">'+n.vars.nextText+"</a></li></ul>");n.customDirectionNav?n.directionNav=n.customDirectionNav:n.controlsContainer?($(n.controlsContainer).append(e),n.directionNav=$("."+i+"direction-nav li a",n.controlsContainer)):(n.append(e),n.directionNav=$("."+i+"direction-nav li a",n)),f.directionNav.update(),n.directionNav.bind(o,function(e){e.preventDefault();var t;""!==l&&l!==e.type||(t=$(this).hasClass(i+"next")?n.getTarget("next"):n.getTarget("prev"),n.flexAnimate(t,n.vars.pauseOnAction)),""===l&&(l=e.type),f.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},update:function(){var e=i+"disabled";1===n.pagingCount?n.directionNav.addClass(e).attr("tabindex","-1"):n.vars.animationLoop?n.directionNav.removeClass(e).removeAttr("tabindex"):0===n.animatingTo?n.directionNav.removeClass(e).filter("."+i+"prev").addClass(e).attr("tabindex","-1"):n.animatingTo===n.last?n.directionNav.removeClass(e).filter("."+i+"next").addClass(e).attr("tabindex","-1"):n.directionNav.removeClass(e).removeAttr("tabindex")}},pausePlay:{setup:function(){var e=$('<div class="'+i+'pauseplay"><a href="#"></a></div>');n.controlsContainer?(n.controlsContainer.append(e),n.pausePlay=$("."+i+"pauseplay a",n.controlsContainer)):(n.append(e),n.pausePlay=$("."+i+"pauseplay a",n)),f.pausePlay.update(n.vars.slideshow?i+"pause":i+"play"),n.pausePlay.bind(o,function(e){e.preventDefault(),""!==l&&l!==e.type||($(this).hasClass(i+"pause")?(n.manualPause=!0,n.manualPlay=!1,n.pause()):(n.manualPause=!1,n.manualPlay=!0,n.play())),""===l&&(l=e.type),f.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},update:function(e){"play"===e?n.pausePlay.removeClass(i+"pause").addClass(i+"play").html(n.vars.playText):n.pausePlay.removeClass(i+"play").addClass(i+"pause").html(n.vars.pauseText)}},touch:function(){function e(e){e.stopPropagation(),n.animating?e.preventDefault():(n.pause(),t._gesture.addPointer(e.pointerId),T=0,c=d?n.h:n.w,f=Number(new Date),l=v&&u&&n.animatingTo===n.last?0:v&&u?n.limit-(n.itemW+n.vars.itemMargin)*n.move*n.animatingTo:v&&n.currentSlide===n.last?n.limit:v?(n.itemW+n.vars.itemMargin)*n.move*n.currentSlide:u?(n.last-n.currentSlide+n.cloneOffset)*c:(n.currentSlide+n.cloneOffset)*c)}function a(e){e.stopPropagation();var a=e.target._slider;if(a){var n=-e.translationX,i=-e.translationY;return T+=d?i:n,m=T,y=d?Math.abs(T)<Math.abs(-n):Math.abs(T)<Math.abs(-i),e.detail===e.MSGESTURE_FLAG_INERTIA?void setImmediate(function(){t._gesture.stop()}):void((!y||Number(new Date)-f>500)&&(e.preventDefault(),!p&&a.transitions&&(a.vars.animationLoop||(m=T/(0===a.currentSlide&&0>T||a.currentSlide===a.last&&T>0?Math.abs(T)/c+2:1)),a.setProps(l+m,"setTouch"))))}}function i(e){e.stopPropagation();var t=e.target._slider;if(t){if(t.animatingTo===t.currentSlide&&!y&&null!==m){var a=u?-m:m,n=a>0?t.getTarget("next"):t.getTarget("prev");t.canAdvance(n)&&(Number(new Date)-f<550&&Math.abs(a)>50||Math.abs(a)>c/2)?t.flexAnimate(n,t.vars.pauseOnAction):p||t.flexAnimate(t.currentSlide,t.vars.pauseOnAction,!0)}r=null,o=null,m=null,l=null,T=0}}var r,o,l,c,m,f,g,h,S,y=!1,x=0,b=0,T=0;s?(t.style.msTouchAction="none",t._gesture=new MSGesture,t._gesture.target=t,t.addEventListener("MSPointerDown",e,!1),t._slider=n,t.addEventListener("MSGestureChange",a,!1),t.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd",i,!1)):(g=function(e){n.animating?e.preventDefault():(window.navigator.msPointerEnabled||1===e.touches.length)&&(n.pause(),c=d?n.h:n.w,f=Number(new Date),x=e.touches[0].pageX,b=e.touches[0].pageY,l=v&&u&&n.animatingTo===n.last?0:v&&u?n.limit-(n.itemW+n.vars.itemMargin)*n.move*n.animatingTo:v&&n.currentSlide===n.last?n.limit:v?(n.itemW+n.vars.itemMargin)*n.move*n.currentSlide:u?(n.last-n.currentSlide+n.cloneOffset)*c:(n.currentSlide+n.cloneOffset)*c,r=d?b:x,o=d?x:b,t.addEventListener("touchmove",h,!1),t.addEventListener("touchend",S,!1))},h=function(e){x=e.touches[0].pageX,b=e.touches[0].pageY,m=d?r-b:r-x,y=d?Math.abs(m)<Math.abs(x-o):Math.abs(m)<Math.abs(b-o);var t=500;(!y||Number(new Date)-f>t)&&(e.preventDefault(),!p&&n.transitions&&(n.vars.animationLoop||(m/=0===n.currentSlide&&0>m||n.currentSlide===n.last&&m>0?Math.abs(m)/c+2:1),n.setProps(l+m,"setTouch")))},S=function(e){if(t.removeEventListener("touchmove",h,!1),n.animatingTo===n.currentSlide&&!y&&null!==m){var a=u?-m:m,i=a>0?n.getTarget("next"):n.getTarget("prev");n.canAdvance(i)&&(Number(new Date)-f<550&&Math.abs(a)>50||Math.abs(a)>c/2)?n.flexAnimate(i,n.vars.pauseOnAction):p||n.flexAnimate(n.currentSlide,n.vars.pauseOnAction,!0)}t.removeEventListener("touchend",S,!1),r=null,o=null,m=null,l=null},t.addEventListener("touchstart",g,!1))},resize:function(){!n.animating&&n.is(":visible")&&(v||n.doMath(),p?f.smoothHeight():v?(n.slides.width(n.computedW),n.update(n.pagingCount),n.setProps()):d?(n.viewport.height(n.h),n.setProps(n.h,"setTotal")):(n.vars.smoothHeight&&f.smoothHeight(),n.newSlides.width(n.computedW),n.setProps(n.computedW,"setTotal")))},smoothHeight:function(e){if(!d||p){var t=p?n:n.viewport;e?t.animate({height:n.slides.eq(n.animatingTo).innerHeight()},e):t.innerHeight(n.slides.eq(n.animatingTo).innerHeight())}},sync:function(e){var t=$(n.vars.sync).data("flexslider"),a=n.animatingTo;switch(e){case"animate":t.flexAnimate(a,n.vars.pauseOnAction,!1,!0);break;case"play":t.playing||t.asNav||t.play();break;case"pause":t.pause()}},uniqueID:function(e){return e.filter("[id]").add(e.find("[id]")).each(function(){var e=$(this);e.attr("id",e.attr("id")+"_clone")}),e},pauseInvisible:{visProp:null,init:function(){var e=f.pauseInvisible.getHiddenProp();if(e){var t=e.replace(/[H|h]idden/,"")+"visibilitychange";document.addEventListener(t,function(){f.pauseInvisible.isHidden()?n.startTimeout?clearTimeout(n.startTimeout):n.pause():n.started?n.play():n.vars.initDelay>0?setTimeout(n.play,n.vars.initDelay):n.play()})}},isHidden:function(){var e=f.pauseInvisible.getHiddenProp();return e?document[e]:!1},getHiddenProp:function(){var e=["webkit","moz","ms","o"];if("hidden"in document)return"hidden";for(var t=0;t<e.length;t++)if(e[t]+"Hidden"in document)return e[t]+"Hidden";return null}},setToClearWatchedEvent:function(){clearTimeout(c),c=setTimeout(function(){l=""},3e3)}},n.flexAnimate=function(e,t,a,s,o){if(n.vars.animationLoop||e===n.currentSlide||(n.direction=e>n.currentSlide?"next":"prev"),m&&1===n.pagingCount&&(n.direction=n.currentItem<e?"next":"prev"),!n.animating&&(n.canAdvance(e,o)||a)&&n.is(":visible")){if(m&&s){var l=$(n.vars.asNavFor).data("flexslider");if(n.atEnd=0===e||e===n.count-1,l.flexAnimate(e,!0,!1,!0,o),n.direction=n.currentItem<e?"next":"prev",l.direction=n.direction,Math.ceil((e+1)/n.visible)-1===n.currentSlide||0===e)return n.currentItem=e,n.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(e).addClass(i+"active-slide"),!1;n.currentItem=e,n.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(e).addClass(i+"active-slide"),e=Math.floor(e/n.visible)}if(n.animating=!0,n.animatingTo=e,t&&n.pause(),n.vars.before(n),n.syncExists&&!o&&f.sync("animate"),n.vars.controlNav&&f.controlNav.active(),v||n.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(e).addClass(i+"active-slide"),n.atEnd=0===e||e===n.last,n.vars.directionNav&&f.directionNav.update(),e===n.last&&(n.vars.end(n),n.vars.animationLoop||n.pause()),p)r?(n.slides.eq(n.currentSlide).css({opacity:0,zIndex:1}),n.slides.eq(e).css({opacity:1,zIndex:2}),n.wrapup(c)):(n.slides.eq(n.currentSlide).css({zIndex:1}).animate({opacity:0},n.vars.animationSpeed,n.vars.easing),n.slides.eq(e).css({zIndex:2}).animate({opacity:1},n.vars.animationSpeed,n.vars.easing,n.wrapup));else{var c=d?n.slides.filter(":first").height():n.computedW,g,h,S;v?(g=n.vars.itemMargin,S=(n.itemW+g)*n.move*n.animatingTo,h=S>n.limit&&1!==n.visible?n.limit:S):h=0===n.currentSlide&&e===n.count-1&&n.vars.animationLoop&&"next"!==n.direction?u?(n.count+n.cloneOffset)*c:0:n.currentSlide===n.last&&0===e&&n.vars.animationLoop&&"prev"!==n.direction?u?0:(n.count+1)*c:u?(n.count-1-e+n.cloneOffset)*c:(e+n.cloneOffset)*c,n.setProps(h,"",n.vars.animationSpeed),n.transitions?(n.vars.animationLoop&&n.atEnd||(n.animating=!1,n.currentSlide=n.animatingTo),n.container.unbind("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend"),n.container.bind("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend",function(){clearTimeout(n.ensureAnimationEnd),n.wrapup(c)}),clearTimeout(n.ensureAnimationEnd),n.ensureAnimationEnd=setTimeout(function(){n.wrapup(c)},n.vars.animationSpeed+100)):n.container.animate(n.args,n.vars.animationSpeed,n.vars.easing,function(){n.wrapup(c)})}n.vars.smoothHeight&&f.smoothHeight(n.vars.animationSpeed)}},n.wrapup=function(e){p||v||(0===n.currentSlide&&n.animatingTo===n.last&&n.vars.animationLoop?n.setProps(e,"jumpEnd"):n.currentSlide===n.last&&0===n.animatingTo&&n.vars.animationLoop&&n.setProps(e,"jumpStart")),n.animating=!1,n.currentSlide=n.animatingTo,n.vars.after(n)},n.animateSlides=function(){!n.animating&&e&&n.flexAnimate(n.getTarget("next"))},n.pause=function(){clearInterval(n.animatedSlides),n.animatedSlides=null,n.playing=!1,n.vars.pausePlay&&f.pausePlay.update("play"),n.syncExists&&f.sync("pause")},n.play=function(){n.playing&&clearInterval(n.animatedSlides),n.animatedSlides=n.animatedSlides||setInterval(n.animateSlides,n.vars.slideshowSpeed),n.started=n.playing=!0,n.vars.pausePlay&&f.pausePlay.update("pause"),n.syncExists&&f.sync("play")},n.stop=function(){n.pause(),n.stopped=!0},n.canAdvance=function(e,t){var a=m?n.pagingCount-1:n.last;return t?!0:m&&n.currentItem===n.count-1&&0===e&&"prev"===n.direction?!0:m&&0===n.currentItem&&e===n.pagingCount-1&&"next"!==n.direction?!1:e!==n.currentSlide||m?n.vars.animationLoop?!0:n.atEnd&&0===n.currentSlide&&e===a&&"next"!==n.direction?!1:!n.atEnd||n.currentSlide!==a||0!==e||"next"!==n.direction:!1},n.getTarget=function(e){return n.direction=e,"next"===e?n.currentSlide===n.last?0:n.currentSlide+1:0===n.currentSlide?n.last:n.currentSlide-1},n.setProps=function(e,t,a){var i=function(){var a=e?e:(n.itemW+n.vars.itemMargin)*n.move*n.animatingTo,i=function(){if(v)return"setTouch"===t?e:u&&n.animatingTo===n.last?0:u?n.limit-(n.itemW+n.vars.itemMargin)*n.move*n.animatingTo:n.animatingTo===n.last?n.limit:a;switch(t){case"setTotal":return u?(n.count-1-n.currentSlide+n.cloneOffset)*e:(n.currentSlide+n.cloneOffset)*e;case"setTouch":return u?e:e;case"jumpEnd":return u?e:n.count*e;case"jumpStart":return u?n.count*e:e;default:return e}}();return-1*i+"px"}();n.transitions&&(i=d?"translate3d(0,"+i+",0)":"translate3d("+i+",0,0)",a=void 0!==a?a/1e3+"s":"0s",n.container.css("-"+n.pfx+"-transition-duration",a),n.container.css("transition-duration",a)),n.args[n.prop]=i,(n.transitions||void 0===a)&&n.container.css(n.args),n.container.css("transform",i)},n.setup=function(e){if(p)n.slides.css({width:"100%","float":"left",marginRight:"-100%",position:"relative"}),"init"===e&&(r?n.slides.css({opacity:0,display:"block",webkitTransition:"opacity "+n.vars.animationSpeed/1e3+"s ease",zIndex:1}).eq(n.currentSlide).css({opacity:1,zIndex:2}):0==n.vars.fadeFirstSlide?n.slides.css({opacity:0,display:"block",zIndex:1}).eq(n.currentSlide).css({zIndex:2}).css({opacity:1}):n.slides.css({opacity:0,display:"block",zIndex:1}).eq(n.currentSlide).css({zIndex:2}).animate({opacity:1},n.vars.animationSpeed,n.vars.easing)),n.vars.smoothHeight&&f.smoothHeight();else{var t,a;"init"===e&&(n.viewport=$('<div class="'+i+'viewport"></div>').css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"}).appendTo(n).append(n.container),n.cloneCount=0,n.cloneOffset=0,u&&(a=$.makeArray(n.slides).reverse(),n.slides=$(a),n.container.empty().append(n.slides))),n.vars.animationLoop&&!v&&(n.cloneCount=2,n.cloneOffset=1,"init"!==e&&n.container.find(".clone").remove(),n.container.append(f.uniqueID(n.slides.first().clone().addClass("clone")).attr("aria-hidden","true")).prepend(f.uniqueID(n.slides.last().clone().addClass("clone")).attr("aria-hidden","true"))),n.newSlides=$(n.vars.selector,n),t=u?n.count-1-n.currentSlide+n.cloneOffset:n.currentSlide+n.cloneOffset,d&&!v?(n.container.height(200*(n.count+n.cloneCount)+"%").css("position","absolute").width("100%"),setTimeout(function(){n.newSlides.css({display:"block"}),n.doMath(),n.viewport.height(n.h),n.setProps(t*n.h,"init")},"init"===e?100:0)):(n.container.width(200*(n.count+n.cloneCount)+"%"),n.setProps(t*n.computedW,"init"),setTimeout(function(){n.doMath(),n.newSlides.css({width:n.computedW,marginRight:n.computedM,"float":"left",display:"block"}),n.vars.smoothHeight&&f.smoothHeight()},"init"===e?100:0))}v||n.slides.removeClass(i+"active-slide").eq(n.currentSlide).addClass(i+"active-slide"),n.vars.init(n)},n.doMath=function(){var e=n.slides.first(),t=n.vars.itemMargin,a=n.vars.minItems,i=n.vars.maxItems;n.w=void 0===n.viewport?n.width():n.viewport.width(),n.h=e.height(),n.boxPadding=e.outerWidth()-e.width(),v?(n.itemT=n.vars.itemWidth+t,n.itemM=t,n.minW=a?a*n.itemT:n.w,n.maxW=i?i*n.itemT-t:n.w,n.itemW=n.minW>n.w?(n.w-t*(a-1))/a:n.maxW<n.w?(n.w-t*(i-1))/i:n.vars.itemWidth>n.w?n.w:n.vars.itemWidth,n.visible=Math.floor(n.w/n.itemW),n.move=n.vars.move>0&&n.vars.move<n.visible?n.vars.move:n.visible,n.pagingCount=Math.ceil((n.count-n.visible)/n.move+1),n.last=n.pagingCount-1,n.limit=1===n.pagingCount?0:n.vars.itemWidth>n.w?n.itemW*(n.count-1)+t*(n.count-1):(n.itemW+t)*n.count-n.w-t):(n.itemW=n.w,n.itemM=t,n.pagingCount=n.count,n.last=n.count-1),n.computedW=n.itemW-n.boxPadding,n.computedM=n.itemM},n.update=function(e,t){n.doMath(),v||(e<n.currentSlide?n.currentSlide+=1:e<=n.currentSlide&&0!==e&&(n.currentSlide-=1),n.animatingTo=n.currentSlide),n.vars.controlNav&&!n.manualControls&&("add"===t&&!v||n.pagingCount>n.controlNav.length?f.controlNav.update("add"):("remove"===t&&!v||n.pagingCount<n.controlNav.length)&&(v&&n.currentSlide>n.last&&(n.currentSlide-=1,n.animatingTo-=1),f.controlNav.update("remove",n.last))),n.vars.directionNav&&f.directionNav.update()},n.addSlide=function(e,t){var a=$(e);n.count+=1,n.last=n.count-1,d&&u?void 0!==t?n.slides.eq(n.count-t).after(a):n.container.prepend(a):void 0!==t?n.slides.eq(t).before(a):n.container.append(a),n.update(t,"add"),n.slides=$(n.vars.selector+":not(.clone)",n),n.setup(),n.vars.added(n)},n.removeSlide=function(e){var t=isNaN(e)?n.slides.index($(e)):e;n.count-=1,n.last=n.count-1,isNaN(e)?$(e,n.slides).remove():d&&u?n.slides.eq(n.last).remove():n.slides.eq(e).remove(),n.doMath(),n.update(t,"remove"),n.slides=$(n.vars.selector+":not(.clone)",n),n.setup(),n.vars.removed(n)},f.init()},$(window).blur(function(t){e=!1}).focus(function(t){e=!0}),$.flexslider.defaults={namespace:"flex-",selector:".slides > li",animation:"fade",easing:"swing",direction:"horizontal",reverse:!1,animationLoop:!0,smoothHeight:!1,startAt:0,slideshow:!0,slideshowSpeed:7e3,animationSpeed:600,initDelay:0,randomize:!1,fadeFirstSlide:!0,thumbCaptions:!1,pauseOnAction:!0,pauseOnHover:!1,pauseInvisible:!0,useCSS:!0,touch:!0,video:!1,controlNav:!0,directionNav:!0,prevText:"Previous",nextText:"Next",keyboard:!0,multipleKeyboard:!1,mousewheel:!1,pausePlay:!1,pauseText:"Pause",playText:"Play",controlsContainer:"",manualControls:"",customDirectionNav:"",sync:"",asNavFor:"",itemWidth:0,itemMargin:0,minItems:1,maxItems:0,move:0,allowOneSlide:!0,start:function(){},before:function(){},after:function(){},end:function(){},added:function(){},removed:function(){},init:function(){}},$.fn.flexslider=function(e){if(void 0===e&&(e={}),"object"==typeof e)return this.each(function(){var t=$(this),a=e.selector?e.selector:".slides > li",n=t.find(a);1===n.length&&e.allowOneSlide===!1||0===n.length?(n.fadeIn(400),e.start&&e.start(t)):void 0===t.data("flexslider")&&new $.flexslider(this,e)});var t=$(this).data("flexslider");switch(e){case"play":t.play();break;case"pause":t.pause();break;case"stop":t.stop();break;case"next":t.flexAnimate(t.getTarget("next"),!0);break;case"prev":case"previous":t.flexAnimate(t.getTarget("prev"),!0);break;default:"number"==typeof e&&t.flexAnimate(e,!0)}}}(jQuery);
```

```css
.slider{

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-height: 100vh;/* for demo purpose , reset your own value */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.slides li{
    position: relative;
}
.slides li img {
  width:100%;
  object-fit:none;
  object-position: center center;
}

.slides li{
    max-height: 100vh;/* for demo purpose , reset your own value */
}

.flex-control-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex-control-paging li a{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #f04d43;
}

.flex-active{
    background-color: #404041;
}

.flex-pauseplay{
    display: none;
}


.flex-container a:hover,
.flex-slider a:hover {
  outline: none;
}
.slides,
.slides > li,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.flex-pauseplay span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.flexslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.flexslider .slides > li {
  display: none;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.flexslider .slides:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
html[xmlns] .flexslider .slides {
  display: block;
}
* html .flexslider .slides {
  height: 1%;
}
.no-js .flexslider .slides > li:first-child {
  display: block;
}
.flexslider {
  margin: 0 0 60px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  position: relative;

  border-radius: 4px;
 
  box-shadow:  0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
}
.flex-viewport {
  max-height: 2000px;

  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}
.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f001';
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
  content: '\f002';
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -50px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-align: right;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}

.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: -1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
    top: 40px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f004';
}
.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {
  content: '\f003';
}
.flex-control-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    right: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: block;
  background: #f04d43;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #404041;
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
      <li>
          <img src="http://79.170.40.172/allianceworkforce.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/slider_image.png" alt="" />
      </li>    
    
    <li>
          <img src="http://79.170.40.172/allianceworkforce.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/slider_image.png" alt="" />
      </li>    
    <li>
          <img src="http://79.170.40.172/allianceworkforce.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/slider_image.png" alt="" />
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```